# Electron build failed to load index.html

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to build my electron application with electron-builder, I have successfully built front-end which was react and did also pass `homepage: "./"` in my package.json. I have also used hashbrowser as it was mentioned [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5107#issuecomment-740811430)

but still when I build my app, I get this message in console with white screen:

`Not allowed to load local resource`. I have passed webSecurity: false in webPreferences electron, It made error go away but didn't fix the problem and still getting white page.

this is my electron index.ts:

```
let mainWindow: BrowserWindow;

const createWidnow = () => {
  mainWindowFunctions();

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    minHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 800,
    x: appXAndY.x,
    y: appXAndY.y,
    width: appWidthAndHeight.width,
    height: appWidthAndHeight.height,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),web
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev ? "http://localhost:3000/" : `file://${__dirname}/../build/index.html`
  );

  if (isDev) {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }
}

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  createWidnow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWidnow();
    }
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    db.close();
    app.quit();
  }
});

const mainWindowFunctions = () => {
  const files = glob.sync(
    path.join(__dirname, "./controllers/**/*.js").split(path.sep).join("/")
  );
  files.forEach((file) => {
    require(file);
  });
};
```

I tried webSecurity false but didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with [Electron Packager](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager). Just use [Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/). Then you can get the installer using [wix3](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3).